# im2double giving 1*1 matrix on applying to 256*256 matrix in matlab R2014a

Tags: matlab

I want to convert a 256*256 matrix type uint8  to 256*256 matrix of type double but when  I use im2double() it gives me a 1*1 matrix  of type double.

I want to do a gamma transformation to my image for that I need to use power function which in turn requires me to use matrix of type double because value of gamma that user will enter will of of double type and power function says that it can operate when matrix and scalar are both of same type i.e. double

The code is as follows:

```html
b=imread('cameraman.tif');
[m,n] = size(b);
c=input('enter value of c');
gamma=input('enter value of gamma');
I2 = im2double(b);

for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
        
        I2=c*power(I2(i,j),gamma);
               
       
    end
end
    
    imshow(I2,[]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `im2double`, your matrix `b` is just that, a `[256 x 256]` matrix. Just use `double(b)`, or, as a one liner: `b=double(imread('cameraman.tif'));`

You can most probably improve on the `for` loop as well (by completely removing it in favour of vectorising your equation), use `bsxfun`:

```
I2 = c*bsxfun(@power, b, gamma);
```

Just as an afterthought:

```
I2 = c*b.^gamma;
```

might work, but I have not tested this.

Comment: im2double is still giving me 1*1 matrix and when i use  bsxfun function it gives this error "Integers can only be raised to positive integral powers." after i convert using double as u suggested in first line .But Your second solution works good. I can't use the im2double function but in the documentation and other examples on internet its working fine . Any clue about that . Thanks for the ans though the code started working .